# Retrieve sessions list from sessionStore and destroy user previous sessions NodeJS

Tags: node.js, session, mongoose, meanjs, express-session

I need to retrieve a list sessions from sessionStore(MongoStore) and delete previous login session. I am using express-session to store sessions in DB.

```
var userId = req.query.userid;
  if (!userId)
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage('No user found in input request')
    });

  var store = req.sessionStore;
  var sessionsColl = store.db.collection('sessions');

  sessionsColl.find({
    'session.passport.user': userId,
    '_id': { '$ne': req.sessionID }
  }, function (err, userSessions) {
    console.log(userSessions);
    if (userSessions !== null && typeof userSessions._id !== 'undefined') {
      store.destroy(userSessions._id, function (err, dat) {
        console.log(dat);
      });      
    }
  });
```

But in **userSessions** object i am getting an object instead of collection and I could not understand how can I fetch list of sessions from **userSessions** object

[image: userSessions object response]

Answer (score 2):

Finally with the little I would be able solve the issue
Here is my code

```
    exports.logoutFromPreviousDevices = function (req, res) {
  var userId = req.query.userid;
  if (!userId)
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage('No user found in input request')
    });

  var store = req.sessionStore;
  var sessionsColl = store.db.collection('sessions');

  sessionsColl.find({
    // 'session.passport.user': userId,
    // we are tryin to remove all sessions, you can leave current
    // '_id': { '$ne': req.sessionID }
  }, function (err, userSessions) {
    if (userSessions !== null) {
      userSessions.toArray(function (a, sessionsData) {
        sessionsData.forEach(function (element, index) {
          var data = JSON.parse(element.session);
          if (element._id !== req.sessionID && req.query.userid === data.passport.user) {
            store.destroy(element._id, function (destroyerr, dat) {
              if (destroyerr)
                return res.status(400).send({
                  message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(destroyerr)
                });
              res.jsonp({ status: 'Previous session deleted' });
            });
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      res.jsonp({ status: 'No session found' });
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below code solve my problem.**

```
var store = req.sessionStore;    
for(var sid in store.sessions){ 
    var ses = JSON.parse(store.sessions[sid]);    
    if(ses.passport.user.username==core_id) {         
        store.destroy(sid, function (err, dat) {                    
        });       
    }
}
```